# c# executing application in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a c# console application which expects some parameters, we are using the same application for multiple purpose and this is driven by changing the parameters passed to the application.

Currently we deploy the code twice in order for us to be able to run this application in parallel with different parameters.

Is there a way where we can get away from having to deploy the application twice and be able to run the application in parallel without having to worry about static variables etc being shared across?

Comment: If you start the same executable 2 times, static variables etc. won't be shared between the two processes: each uses its own memory space. There is no need to "deploy your code" (I assume you meant compile it to build an executable) twice. Maybe I am missing something in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Run each set of parameters in it's own thread.  For console output indicate which task the output is related to, or output to separate files.  Exit the app when all threads have completed.